# how to assign value of readAsDataURL() to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, filereader

okay so I've seen many examples and questions on using readAsDataURL(), but none of them seem to resolve my issue. Following is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(fileReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("userfile").files[0]));
    });
});
```

what i get in console is `undefined` . I'm trying to get the base64 encoded file data on a variable so that i can upload it using ajax. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most methods of a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/FileReader) instance report the results asynchronously.

You have to bind an `onload` event to capture the result:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.result);
};
fileReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("userfile").files[0]);
```

Comment: @PRASANTH No, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility. If you want such an API for IE9-, try a polyfill, e.g. this one: https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader

Comment: Ya Sure thanks for the reply and will let you know if it proves productive