# jQuery file reader not working

Tags: jquery, html

jquery code:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL($("#img1").val());
    reader.onload = function() {
        console.log(reader.result);
    };
```

Html code:

```
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img1">
```

I don't know why it not working can anyone please help me How to resolve this Error?

Comment: because it does not want a jQuery object

Comment: can you please write an answer because I don't understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998610/how-to-assign-value-of-readasdataurl-to-a-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to assign value of readAsDataURL() to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998610/how-to-assign-value-of-readasdataurl-to-a-variable)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileReader `readAsDataURL()` function requires an HTML5 Blob or File object, not a jQuery object. See [FileReader.readAsDataURL() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

In your example you can achieve uploading the file this way:

```js
var file = document.getElementById('img1').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var res = reader.result; 
    console.log(res);
});

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: How can I save data in variable?

Comment: @RushabhShah If you mean selecting multiple files at once, you can achieve this by looping through `document.getElementById('img1').files`. You need to create a new FileReader for each file to read.